# Auto increment in excel for alternative cell?

Tags: excel, auto-increment

Please check the eg.

> row - value
>
> 1 - test1
>
> 2 - test1
>
> 3 - test2
>
> 4 - test2
>
> 5 - test3
>
> 6 - test3

Like this automatically have to increment in MS-Excel without using any scripts

Please give me a suggestion

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a combination of the row number (`ROW()`) and rounding to get your desired result:

```
="test" & ROUND(ROW() / 2, 0)
```

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables: Thanks for quick response... can you tell me how to implement this in excel?

Comment: It's a formula.  You enter it into cell A1 and copy down as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly what you were looking for, and it requires a bit of a workaround, but it worked for me on a known quantity of rows.

It relies on Excel's built-in ability to figure out a fill series.

First, you set up your data like this instead. We skipped a row for each incrementing data point.

[image: data setup]

Then you highlight the data **and include the row below it**, like this:

[image: data highlight]

Now, since you are using two rows for each data point, drag the fill handle down to an **even-numbered row**:

[image: data drag down]

Now we use the well-known technique for filling in blanks:

- Go to Special, Blanks:

[image: go to special, blanks]

- Type `=`, ↑, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (equals sign, up arrow, Ctrl+Enter)

[image: data formula]

- Highlight the values, copy (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) and Paste Values.